# Do I have to create separate cookies for every drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to js but I've managed to create a site that has a bunch of drop down menus with values (ranging from 1 - 10) inside. If the user screws up, or reloads/closes browser, any value they selected will disappear. I've managed to figure out how to create cookies in Firefox with local files - Chrome was a lost cause.

So basically, i'm sure I can figure out how to manipulate created cookies to pre-select drop down menu entries if the user reloads the page, but do I have to do that with every single drop-down-list?

Comment: Have you considered using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Answer (score 2):

Cookies aren't a great fit for purely client-side information, because they get attached to all the HTTP requests from the client to your site.

Instead, I'd use [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) (either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`), which [has excellent support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).

You can have an object with properties for each thing you want to save:

```
var settings = {
   a: "one",
   b: "two"
   // ...
};
```

Whenever you want to save it (e.g., when user changes something):

```
localStorage.settings = JSON.stringify(settings);
```

On page load, to retrieve it:

```
var settings = JSON.parse(localStorage.settings || "null") || {
    a: "default",
    b: "default"
    // ...
};
```

Then use `settings.a`, and such to set the values in the lists.

Comment: Ha ha... Best as usual... `:)`

Comment: Thanks T.J. Looks good. I'm going to do a bit of a crash course in localStorage to get the gist and compare with your code. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `#hash-bangs` in your URL to make this work. One simple example is:

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").val(window.location.hash.substr(1)).keyup(function () {
    if (history.pushState) {
      history.pushState(null, null, '#' + $(this).val());
    }
    $("pre").text("Current URL is: " + window.location);
  });
  $("pre").text("Current URL is: " + window.location);
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
pre {font-family: 'Consolas';}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" />
<pre></pre>
```

You can see the output here: **http://output.jsbin.com/yaheyurivi**

If you wanna store and retrieve multiple values, you can do it using `Serialize()`. Create an object of multiple pairs of keys and values. Let's try the above same example with two inputs.

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").keyup(function () {
    if (history.pushState) {
      history.pushState(null, null, '#' + $("form").serialize());
    }
    $("pre").text("Current URL is: " + window.location);
  });
  // read the elements from the URL
  var theHash = location.hash.substr(1);
  // split the params
  theHash = theHash.split("&");
  // assign each
  for (i = 0; i < theHash.length; i++) {
    var inputName = theHash[i].split("=")[0];
    var inputValue = theHash[i].split("=")[1];
    $('input[name="' + inputName + '"]').val(inputValue);
  }
  $("pre").text("Current URL is: " + window.location);
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
pre {font-family: 'Consolas';}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  #1: <input id="text1" name="text1" /><br>
  #2: <input id="text2" name="text2" />
</form>
<pre></pre>
```

**Live Example: http://output.jsbin.com/qecilovoxu**

---

Other methods include `LocalStorage` and `Cookies`.

Comment: You might need to demonstrate how that lets them store multiple values.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That would be tooooooo complicated right? `:(`

Comment: But the question was about storing multiple values, this answer doesn't solve that at the moment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Check my answer now. `:)`